# Shorten months ticks on x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I shorten the months label, from October to Oct.

When the default graph shows October, it should display Oct. and the years should be kept.

I think I should use

```
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
```

but when I use it, the years are not shown.

How can I apply the `tickFormat` only if the legend displays a month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with such customisations is that in D3 axes are automatically generated, and setting some things like the exact amount of ticks can be frustratingly difficult. The situation is even more complicated in a time scale, which makes your case worse: in a time scale it's hard to know beforehand how the ticks will be formatted.

As you already know, converting *all* ticks to the month's abbreviation is easy. However, if you want to keep the default structure and change only the ticks with months, you'll have to modify the axis **after** it was created. In this example, using `each`.

So, let's first create a default axis. Here it is:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date("06-01-2016"), new Date("06-01-2017")]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .ticks(4);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

As you can see, we have four ticks: three ticks with full months and one tick with the year.

Now let's check the format of each tick using `this` and comparing with the datum (`d`), converting the text to abbreviated month name only if it is already a month:

```
gX.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d) {
  if (this.textContent === d3.timeFormat("%B")(d)) {
    d3.select(this).select("text").text(d3.timeFormat("%b")(d))
  }
})
```

Here is the result:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date("06-01-2016"), new Date("06-01-2017")]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .ticks(4);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);

gX.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d) {
  if (this.textContent === d3.timeFormat("%B")(d)) {
    d3.select(this).select("text").text(d3.timeFormat("%b")(d))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```